# How do I have different colours of text in an HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts

So I'm trying to make this canvas have different types of text on it including colours. Here what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200" style=" border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function(){
         context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
         context.font = "40pt Calibri";
         context.fillText("My TEXT!", 50, 100);
     };
     imageObj.src = "Assets/Background2.png"; 
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by “text type”? The font? Text color, text size _and_ font? Just set `context.font` to something different after `context.fillText`.

Comment: @Xufox thank you, I really new at this. How do I changed the text color?

Comment: @AnomousPerson use `context.fillStyle = [color]`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the **fillStyle** method each time you want to change your font color:

```
context.fillStyle = 'red';
```

Comment: And `context.font` for font and font size.

Answer (score 1):

Use **fillStyle** before **fillText**

Check this `Fiddle`